# Finding an isomorphism between two structures

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $S = \{A \mid A + A^{T} = 0\}$ be a subspace of the vector space of $2\times 2$ matrices with all real entries. Find an isomorphism between $S$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for some $n$.

---

I wrote entries for $A$. The equality implies $a_{00} = 0$, $a_{11} = 0$, and $a_{01} + a_{10} = 0$.

I'm not sure how I can find an isomorphism though. I know the function needs to be both linear and invertible. Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is the dimension of $S$?

Comment: The dimension is two

Comment: From what you did:
$$
S = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & r \\ -r & 0 \end{pmatrix} : r \in \mathbb R \right\}.
$$

Comment: But don't we need to have r = 0?

Comment: i understand this but I am a bit confused by how to get an isomorphism from it @azif00. also, don't we need r = 0?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What can you say about the map $\Bbb R \to S$, $r \mapsto \big( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & r \\ -r & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \big)$?

Comment: I know that the map $r \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 0 & r \\ -r & 0\end{pmatrix}$ is bijective because we can form every element in $S$ by picking $r$ carefully

Comment: The dimension is not 2. How many parameters do you need to specify an element of $S$?

Comment: Oh I get it. The dimension is 1 because it's only a function of $r$